# Plesk panel replace self signed certificate

Tags: windows, ssl, iis, port, plesk

My plesk panel is located at `https://somedomain.com:8443`. I need to add both `https` and `8443` in order to properly connect to the panel. However, Google Chrome (and so do the other browsers) warns me about the certificate and I need to acknowledge the problem before I can continue to the webpage. I want to add an SSL certificate to it which is (more or less) globally recognized (so I don't get the SSL error message any more).

What I tried:

- I added a subdomain in the plesk interface (`admin.somedomain.com`) and setup an IIS rewrite rule, so port 8443 would automatically be added. I also installed an SSL certificate for `admin.somedomain.com`. When going for `admin.somedomain.com`, it redirects me to `https://admin.somedomain.com:8443` (which is okay), however, the problem persists. The SSL certificate is not recongized.

What I want (summarized): A properly working SSL certificate for the plesk panel.

Comment: Well what error do you get regarding the SSL certificate. Can you send a screenshot of the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just upload your SSL certificate in Plesk in `Tools & Settings > SSL/TLS Certificates` and set it by `Certificate for securing Plesk`:

[image: secure SSL plesk 8443 port panel]